# Route my internet through a website's server

Tags: google-chrome, internet, proxy

Good day,
I have a 4 Mbps internet plan but i have noticed that my ISP allows around 22 Mbps bandwidth for youtube / google servers only.

I have verified this by installing "google data compression proxy extension" in chrome. Speed test (download) results now give 22+/-2 Mbps speed. Disabling the extension drops the speed to 4Mbps.

Is there any way to implement this system wide?

Comment: Do you mean you want to route all internet connections through youtube / google servers? Do you know if this includes Google cloud servers?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton how can i check if cloud servers are included?